# Adding elements dynamically in Grid Columns

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

Can i add elements dynamically into Grid columns? I have this

```
<phone:LongListSelector>
```

inside a grid with 2 columns. 
I want add each object of my list into a StackPanel but adding dinamicaly in the correct column. First element in column 1,
second element in column 2, third element in column 1, fourth element in column 2...
I can do this writing code in .cs file but i will need to create each element programmatically, add each properties and finally add
the element in correct column. Can i do this with xaml?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MyLongListSelector">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                My content here
            </StackPanel>
        <DataTemplate>

        (...)
```

Comment: Is each the stack panel going to have different XAML. For example the item 1 in the list will have a button. Item 2 will have a button and an Image. Item 3 will have only a textbox? Or will each item have the same XAML with a textbox a button and an image for example.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an ItemsControl with Data Templates. 
[ItemsControl Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer. An answer would need you to at least explain how to use said `ItemsControl` with `Data Templates`. Redirecting someone to a link should be done in comments